# why isn't this local image reference in my url-matched view method via being rendered?

Tags: django

i'm pretty well thru the django tutorials, and was feeling pretty good about how it is going.

but then i started to try to use [these suggestions for integrating matplotlib](http://bitsofpy.blogspot.nl/2009/07/matplotlib-in-django.html).  a first step is to include a static image and that's what i'm trying to do.  details:

my file hierachy looks like this:

```
djOakData:
    djOakData:
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    manage.py
    showCrime:
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        models.py
        templates:
            showCrime:
                index.html
        tests.py
        tstImage.JPG
        urls.py
        views.py
    sqlite.db
    templates:
        base_site.html
```

`djOakData/urls.py` has:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

from showCrime import views
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^showCrime/', include('showCrime.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

`djOakData/showCrime/urls.py` has:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
import views
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
        url(r'^tstImage.JPG$', views.index, name='showImage'),
)
```

`djOakData/showCrime/views.py` has:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse 
from django.template import Context, loader

def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('showCrime/index.html')
    context = context = Context({})
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))

def showImage(request):
    imagePath = "/Users/rik/Code/eclipse/djOakData/showCrime/tstImage.JPG"
    from PIL import Image
    Image.init()
    i = Image.open(imagePath)
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='image/jpg')
    i.save(response,'JPG')
    return response
```

and then my `index.html` has just this in it:

```
<h1>ShowCrime Index</h1>
<img src="/showCrime/tstImage.JPG" width="500px">
```

(also tried leaving off the `/showCrime`; still no go.)

i've tried lots of other variants. many of them throw 404 errors, but this version does not. rather, i get just the sort of messages in the log i'd expect, either trying to reference the image via index.html or trying to point at it directly:

```
[11/May/2013 13:50:44] "GET /showCrime/tstImage.JPG HTTP/1.1" 200 391
[11/May/2013 13:50:44] "GET /showCrime/ HTTP/1.1" 200 391
```

any guesses as to what newby thing i'm doing?  thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tstImage url is pointing to the index view, not the showImage one.

Comment: bravo, your eyes found this immediately!  for extra points:  why isn't this throwing any useful error anywhere?  in any case, fixing it made me then realize PIL wasn't installed, and now PIL/image.py is throwing a 'JPG' key error, but i'd say you solved the problem i described here.  thanks Daniel.

Comment: Because it's still a valid URL, it's just pointing to the index view instead of the image.